# Is it possible to use Oracle's Change notification using NHibernate?

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate, change-notification

My project uses NHibernate to access database tables (Oracle). Is it possible to use Oracle [change notification feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-mar/o26odpnet-093584.html) in NHibernate? Or do I have to use Oracle DataClient for this? If so, any idea how to combine this cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in NHibernate that could take advantage of Oracle's Change notification.

Its worst problem, from what I've read in your link, is that it requires the connection to stay open.